# Реклама в приложении андроид

Tags: android, реклама, встроенная-реклама

Есть приложение, которое я разработал. В приложение встроен показ рекламы. Интересно, если я свое приложение буду устанавливать на девайсы не через Google Play Market, а например с флешки будут ли мне начисляться деньги за показ рекламы или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ очень простой - будут. Google без разницы на какой площадке распространяется приложение, главное правила admob не нарушать.